# Does the YouTube PWA have tabs or offer session restore?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, progressive-web-app

Like it says on the tin.
I noticed the little install button today and I am already underwhelmed. I can't seem to find a way to 'nest' the windows generated by the 'app' which would make navigating through them a nightmare given the way I operate. (Involving up to 20 YT tabs in Chrome atm.) I also don't like the possibility of losing videos or channels I was coming back to due to a restart for OS updates. Simply putting them in Watch Later isn't always an option like when it comes to entire channels that I'm planning on checking out. So I need a 'session restore' functionality.

So, does anyone know if the Youtube Progressive Web App (PWA) has either of these features? I need to know whether to adopt it or drop it and continue going about things as I always have.

Comment: This is probably better suited to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) as a PWA is a Progressive Web Application.

Comment: Also, you don't mention which OS you're running on, though I presume Windows. On macOS, returning to exactly where you left off is standard behaviour after any reboot/relaunch.

Comment: @Tetsujin  - That also is the case with Windows in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to open multiple instances of the YouTube PWA. I.E. Windows 10 allows to open multiple instances of YoutTube app and you could use the Windows 10 windows handling features to minimize, change the size, stack, etc.

Let say that your OS is Windows 10. To open multiple instances of the YouTube app, just repeat the regular steps to open a Windows 10 app, i.e. click the Start button then the YouTube app icon.

NOTES:

1. Tabs is a Chrome feature. PWA doesn't offer tabs.
2. "restore pages" is a Chrome feature, not a YouTube feature.

   - As of February 13, 2023, related open issue: [PWAs aren't restored with Chrome sessions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=938759)